# Как добиться отправки ботом сообщения на сервер после обработки сообщения пользователем TelegramBoT aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, 1с

Есть телеграмбот, который интегрируется с базой 1С.
Пользователь нажимает на callback_queri и программа просит его ввести данные:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='contact')
async def exportCommand(callback : types.CallbackQuery):
    global answerPer
    answerPer = '/contact'
    await callback.message.answer('Введите ФИО сотрудника, которого вы хотите получить: {ФИО}')
```

Пользователь должен вводить сообщение-ответ в виде ФИО. Дальше обработчик обрабатывает сообщение:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo_message(msg: types.Message):
    if(answerPer == '/contact'):
        text = msg.text + '/contact'
        print(text)
        answerPer = 'it me'
        bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, text)
    else:
        await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, 'It me')
```

Здесь код еще не дописан, но суть в том, что на стороне 1С команда обрабатывается в виде ФИО/contact.
Я же хочу добиться, чтобы он писал ФИО, а написанный текст пользователям обрабатывался и отправлялся на 1С.
1С не парсит те сообщения, которые ему отправляет бот, реагирует только на действия пользователя.
**Подскажите возможно ли вообще такого рода отправка и если да, то как. Заранее спасибо!!!**

Comment: Из вопроса - ничего не понятно. Опишите проблему проще: бот отправляет в 1С, ответа нет ... и т.п.

Comment: Человек нажимает на команду. Бот отправляет вопрос, человек отвечает. Сообщение доходит до 1С и все будет работать, если человек напишет {ФИО}/contact. Я хочу, чтобы пользователь писал просто ФИО, а /contact приписывал бэк на питоне и отправлял 1С

Comment: та часть которая отправляет запрос к 1С, может предварительно проверить "сообщение" и в случае отсутствия "/contact" добавить; и только потом отправить запрос к 1С

Answer (score 0):

Telegram-бот вполне может работать напрямую из 1С, решения уже есть, например "Конструктор ботов телеграм для 1С, редакция 2"